# How and when to deal with database that is down?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

My problem is that I have to deal somehow with cases when database is down in my MVC application. So, should I like `try{} catch{}` to open connection in every controller? Or what is the best practice?

Note:
For sample database access is isolated in few "manager" classes that work repository kind of way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you opening a connection in every controller.  This should be isolated within it's own reusable class.

You may want to check out the repository pattern to implement your data access.

Comment: It is isolated, but I want to know how do I response to user whenever something goes wrong with connection and where do I handle the error.

Comment: Decorate your class with [HandleError] attribute, and when an uncaught exception is thrown, they will be whisked away to the error page (`/Views/Shared/Error.aspx` I believe)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a database connection, in a production database-driven web app, typically this means something bad happened well beyond the scope of your application. About the only thing you can do is give a friendly error message to the user and tell someone responsible for fixing things. Which is a task for your global error handling, not each controller.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first off, if you have a separate database handling routine in every controller, I would start with combining that into a base class or a reusable member.

After that, you should be able to use ASP.NET MVC's `[HandleError]` attribute to specify how to handle errors from your database.